# c++ pattern matching popen() output with strcmp()

Tags: c++, popen, strcmp

I have data coming in from the buffer from a script I run using popen() and I need to do a string comparison (I understand strcmp is the best) prior to writing to a file.

This is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

        char key[] = "Order ID:";
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = popen("scriptfile.sh", "r");
        while (fgets( buff, BUFSIZ, fp)){
                if (!strcmp (key, buff)){
                        std::cout << "Match";
                }else{
                        printf("LS->%s", buff);
                        std::cout << "Good Bye Cruel World!";
                }
        }
        pclose(fp);
}
```

No error, here  [bpaste](https://bpaste.net/show/6f5701ae390f)  is a dump of the running data. see last line for 'Order ID'

Comment: Are you sure you want to match the complete read string (including newline!) against that key, which only looks like the first part of a line?

Comment: I think I am errored on the \n as well.

Answer (score 2):

The if/else statement is doing the opposite of what you think it's doing, because strcmp() outputs 0 when they are a match, so just place a "!" operator in your if statement.

```
if (!strcmp (key, buff))
    std::cout << ".";
```

Go [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) if you would like a more detailed explanation of why this is.

Comment: still no pattern match. All 'Goodbye Cruel World' and no period '.'

Comment: I knew about the 0 for bool yes/positive

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` checks for full equality. Since you're looking for `key:value`, you can't use `strcmp` to check to see if your new string starts with `key`... since `strcmp` will fail (unless `value` happens to be null).

So instead of:

```
if (strcmp(key, buff)) {
```

do:

```
if (strstr(key, buff) == buff) {
```

That will look for the substring `key` in `buff` and return the pointer at which it starts, which you would like to be `buff`.

Alternatively, since you know it HAS to start at the beginning:

```
if (!memcmp(key, buff, sizeof(key) - 1)) {
```

That will just check the bytes in memory. You need the `- 1` at the end since you don't want to check the null byte of `key`.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, possibly a code snippet? Yes I am actually trying to do a key:value query from inbound JSON

Comment: @user3766148 Rewrote it.

Comment: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer  ?  Should I convert to deci?

Comment: At compile. and with if (!memcmp(key, buff, sizeof(key) - 1)) {   I don't get an error but I also do not get a positive match.

Comment: phpMethod1.cpp:12:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]   yes, it is verified data https://bpaste.net/show/41c9221483fc  <-  see last line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64048/discussion-between-user3766148-and-barry).